# PHP 5.3.6 - curl_exec hangs

Tags: php

I am having a odd problem with the php code below.  I have noticed the issue is randomly happened in PHP 5.3.6.  It works every times when I run it in PHP 5.2.5.  Unfortunately we can downgrade the php due to other OCIs issues with 5.2.5, so we have to use 5.3.6.  When the issue is occurred, I don't get any response back at all and it happens randomly.  Please help, I need to get this project done asap.  Thanks.

```
<?php
$url = 'https://www.PayEverywhere.com/api/vtapi.aspx?profile_id=XXXXXXXX&profile_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXX&transaction_type=S&card_number=...';  
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT,TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);  
if ( ! $response = curl_exec($ch) )
{
    echo "Error " . curl_error($ch). "\n";
}
echo $response;        
curl_close ($ch);
?>
```

Comment: heisenbugs are such fun to diagnose. are you sure it's php 5.3.6? maybe you didn't try enough times with other versions to catch an incident.

Comment: I am not 100% sure.  Unfortunately, we have 2 dev servers.  One is with php 5.3.6 and the other server is 5.2.5.  I run the same code in both servers.  For 5.2.5, so far I always got the response back.  For 5.3.6, I got the response sometimes, and didn't get any response sometimes as well.

Comment: check the curl versions of both servers. curl always gives me headaches

Comment: For server with PHP 5.2.5, the cURL Information => libcurl/7.16.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8e zlib/1.2.3.  For server with PHP 5.6.3, the cURL Information => 7.21.2
Age => 3
Features
AsynchDNS => Yes
Debug => No
GSS-Negotiate => No
IDN => No
IPv6 => Yes
Largefile => Yes
NTLM => Yes
SPNEGO => No
SSL => Yes
SSPI => Yes
krb4 => No
libz => Yes
CharConv => No
Protocols => dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, pop3, pop3s, rtsp, scp, sftp, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
Host => i386-pc-win32
SSL Version => OpenSSL/0.9.8r
ZLib Version => 1.2.3
libSSH Version => libssh2/1.2.7.

Comment: Is anyone knows how to recompile curl with OpenSSL.  I found the issue that RIcko M. had before is similar to my issue.  He mentioned in his blog answered Jun 29'11 at 9:55 "The problem was NSS. I recompiled curl with OpenSSL and so far it has not shown any issues." (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308842/php-curl-exec-hangs for details).

Answer (score 0):

After having retrieved the following archives

http://curl.haxx.se/download.html

http://www.openssl.org/source/

http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/dist/index.html

```
# Install Curl
./configure --prefix=/curl/prefix --with-ssl=/ssl/prefix --disable-ipv6

# As curl depends on OpenSSL, install OpenSSL
./configure --prefix=/openssl/prefix

# As OpenSSL depends on Kerberos, install Kerberos
./configure --prefix=/kerberos/prefix
```